# How to rewrite this code with parallel computing or in python

Tags: python, r, parallel-processing

The files **condition.txt** and **gene.txt** both contain 8000000 rows, but have different column sizes in each row. The computing with the following code have run two weeks, but it is still not completed. how to rewrite the following code with with parallel computing in r or in python. The introduction of the problem see **[R code runs too slow,how to rewrite this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394742/r-code-runs-too-slow-how-to-rewrite-this-code).** Thank you.

```
library(compiler)
library(Matrix)
enableJIT(3)
i=0;

con <- file("condition.txt", "r")
con2<-file("gene.txt","r")
x1<-readLines(con,n=-1)
x2<-readLines(con2,n=-1)


str2mat <- function(s) {
  n <- length(s)
  ni <- sapply(s, length)
  s <- unlist(s)
  u <- unique(s)
  spMatrix(nrow=n, ncol=length(u), i=rep(1L:n, ni), j=match(s, u), x=rep(1, length(s)))
}


m1 <- str2mat(strsplit(x1, "|", fixed=TRUE))
m2 <- str2mat(strsplit(x2, "|", fixed=TRUE))
n1 <- rowSums(m1)
n2 <- rowSums(m2)
num <- tcrossprod(m1)*tcrossprod(m2)
n12 <- n1*n2
den <- outer(n12, n12, pmin)
use <- num/den > 0.6
diag(use) <- FALSE
use[lower.tri(use)] <- FALSE
out <- which(use, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

The result of **Rprof** analysis with smaller input file (20 rows) is as fllows:

```
$by.self
                            self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"options"                        0.10    17.86       0.10     17.86
"findCenvVar"                    0.08    14.29       0.14     25.00
"unique"                         0.06    10.71       0.12     21.43
"unlist"                         0.06    10.71       0.12     21.43
"$"                              0.06    10.71       0.06     10.71
"<Anonymous>"                    0.02     3.57       0.52     92.86
"tryCatchOne"                    0.02     3.57       0.46     82.14
"FUN"                            0.02     3.57       0.12     21.43
"findVar"                        0.02     3.57       0.04      7.14
"%in%"                           0.02     3.57       0.02      3.57
".simpleInheritanceGeneric"      0.02     3.57       0.02      3.57
"as.list"                        0.02     3.57       0.02      3.57
"get"                            0.02     3.57       0.02      3.57
"getClassDef"                    0.02     3.57       0.02      3.57
"parent.env"                     0.02     3.57       0.02      3.57

$by.total
                            total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"<Anonymous>"                     0.52     92.86      0.02     3.57
"test"                            0.50     89.29      0.00     0.00
"tryCatchOne"                     0.46     82.14      0.02     3.57
"cmpfun"                          0.46     82.14      0.00     0.00
"doTryCatch"                      0.46     82.14      0.00     0.00
"tryCatch"                        0.46     82.14      0.00     0.00
"tryCatchList"                    0.46     82.14      0.00     0.00
"standardGeneric"                 0.42     75.00      0.00     0.00
"cmp"                             0.32     57.14      0.00     0.00
"cmpCall"                         0.32     57.14      0.00     0.00
"genCode"                         0.32     57.14      0.00     0.00
"h"                               0.28     50.00      0.00     0.00
"tryInline"                       0.28     50.00      0.00     0.00
"initialize"                      0.26     46.43      0.00     0.00
"new"                             0.26     46.43      0.00     0.00
"spMatrix"                        0.24     42.86      0.00     0.00
"str2mat"                         0.24     42.86      0.00     0.00
"cmpCallArgs"                     0.16     28.57      0.00     0.00
"cmpCallSymFun"                   0.16     28.57      0.00     0.00
"findCenvVar"                     0.14     25.00      0.08    14.29
"findLocalsList"                  0.14     25.00      0.00     0.00
"funEnv"                          0.14     25.00      0.00     0.00
"make.functionContext"            0.14     25.00      0.00     0.00
"unique"                          0.12     21.43      0.06    10.71
"unlist"                          0.12     21.43      0.06    10.71
"FUN"                             0.12     21.43      0.02     3.57
"/"                               0.12     21.43      0.00     0.00
"as"                              0.12     21.43      0.00     0.00
"callGeneric"                     0.12     21.43      0.00     0.00
"checkCall"                       0.12     21.43      0.00     0.00
"eval"                            0.12     21.43      0.00     0.00
"findLocalsList1"                 0.12     21.43      0.00     0.00
"options"                         0.10     17.86      0.10    17.86
"cmpForBody"                      0.10     17.86      0.00     0.00
"lapply"                          0.10     17.86      0.00     0.00
".findInheritedMethods"           0.08     14.29      0.00     0.00
"asMethod"                        0.08     14.29      0.00     0.00
"isSymmetric"                     0.08     14.29      0.00     0.00
"$"                               0.06     10.71      0.06    10.71
"cmpBuiltinArgs"                  0.06     10.71      0.00     0.00
"cmpSym"                          0.06     10.71      0.00     0.00
"getInlineInfo"                   0.06     10.71      0.00     0.00
"findVar"                         0.04      7.14      0.02     3.57
".asCoerceMethod"                 0.04      7.14      0.00     0.00
".local"                          0.04      7.14      0.00     0.00
"all.equal"                       0.04      7.14      0.00     0.00
"anyStrings"                      0.04      7.14      0.00     0.00
"cmpPrim1"                        0.04      7.14      0.00     0.00
"findFunDef"                      0.04      7.14      0.00     0.00
"forceSymmetric"                  0.04      7.14      0.00     0.00
"isTRUE"                          0.04      7.14      0.00     0.00
"validityMethod"                  0.04      7.14      0.00     0.00
"validObject"                     0.04      7.14      0.00     0.00
"%in%"                            0.02      3.57      0.02     3.57
".simpleInheritanceGeneric"       0.02      3.57      0.02     3.57
"as.list"                         0.02      3.57      0.02     3.57
"get"                             0.02      3.57      0.02     3.57
"getClassDef"                     0.02      3.57      0.02     3.57
"parent.env"                      0.02      3.57      0.02     3.57
"*"                               0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
".a.e.comb"                       0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
".eligibleSuperClasses"           0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
">"                               0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
"all.equal_num"                   0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
"as.vector"                       0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
"checkSkipLoopCntxt"              0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
"checkSkipLoopCntxtList"          0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
"cmpBuiltin"                      0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
"cmpCallExprFun"                  0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
"cmpComplexAssign"                0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
"cmpPrim2"                        0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
"cmpSetterCall"                   0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
"cmpSetterDispatch"               0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
"cmpSymbolAssign"                 0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
"extends"                         0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
"Filter"                          0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
"findLocVar"                      0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
"is"                              0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
"isBaseVar"                       0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
"isLoopTopFun"                    0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
"match.fun"                       0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
"Matrix"                          0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
"outer"                           0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
"rowSums"                         0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
"sapply"                          0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
"try"                             0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
"trySetterInline"                 0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00
"which"                           0.02      3.57      0.00     0.00

$sample.interval
[1] 0.02

$sampling.time
[1] 0.56
```

Comment: How much memory do you have that you don't run out of memory using `outer` with vectors of length 6.4e13?

Comment: Are you sure that your system is not swapping (which would be extremely slow)?

Comment: Also, have you tested/benchmarked/profiled your code with smaller input files?

Comment: @Roland The result of Rprof analysis is listed

Comment: You should only profile the relevant parts of your code. Setting options takes time, but that time is independent of your data size. You should also see that the time that is spent in `outer` increases quadratic if you profile with increasing input sizes.

Comment: I would implement most of this with Rcpp if you really need it for such big input files.

Comment: I agree with Roland, both in that it's probably swapping and that Rcpp is probably the next thing to try, rather than parallel computing. I suggest providing a reproducible example; that makes it more likely to get help as then people can try their solutions out. See what I did in my answer to the previous question for an example, but be sure to check to see if the numbers I used were reasonable.

Comment: In addition to profiling, it would also help simply to know how far into the code it's able to get on your big data set. Are you able to calculate `n1` and `n2`? How about `num`?

Comment: @Aaron all the memory in my computer workstation is 32G. Now the workstation is calculating  num <- tcrossprod(m1)*tcrossprod(m2) ，There is 7G memory left

Comment: @Aaron My computer workstation is 32G memory and 8-core CPU. Now the workstation is calculating  num <- tcrossprod(m1)*tcrossprod(m2) ，There is 7G memory left

Comment: Does that mean you got the result for `num` or that it's still calculating it?

Comment: it's still calculating num

Comment: @Aaron it's still calculating num

Comment: @user2405694 You can abort this. If it does proceed to the `outer` line it will run out of memory. You really should rewrite this in a more memory efficient way with a compiled language. And of course you should reconsider your whole algorithm.